# No Send Email Submit Action in Sitecore Forms Module

Tags: sitecore-forms

We are on Sitecore 7.2 as of now and will be upgrading to Sitecore 9 soon.

Rather using WFFM planning to use the Sitecore Forms module for few of the business requirements. But most of the requirements need to send an email post submitting the form and I don’t see any Submit action in the Form Module to Send Emails.

Does Sitecore Forms Module not coming with this action OOTB or we need to change any configuration to get that submit action?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sitecore Forms module on Sitecore 9 Initial release comes with only 5 Submit Actions OOTB.

Trigger Goal, Trigger Campaign Activity, Trigger Outcome, Redirect to Page and Save Data

To send email on Submit action either you can use Marketing Automation and send emails by selecting “Trigger Goal” submit action.

Else you can write Custom Save Action to Send Emails.

Else Sitecore 9.0 Update 1 comes with one additional Submit Action – Send Email Campaign Message, try exploring that.

P.S. I haven’t tested the new Submit Action yet, assuming it should work without any issues.

### Update 1:

Also have a look at this Custom Send Email Action, also explaining the issues with OOTB Send Email Campaign Message action with Sitecore Forms:

http://www.nishtechinc.com/Blog/2018/April/Send-E-mail-Action-to-Sitecore-9-Forms

Comment: Do we have any plans to have the send email submit action OOTB in Sitecore Forms?

Comment: 9.0.1 has Send Email Campaign OOTB.

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore 9.0.1 added the send send action.

It works in collaboration with EXM.

Unfortunately, you can only send an email to the current contact filling in the form and you cannot use the content of the form in your email.

If you want to keep using EXM (which I recommend, it is a nice build in sitecore mailing system and easy to setup) you can take a look at my Sitecore Forms Extensions module. Aside to file upload, and captcha controls, it adds support for sending a mail to the backoffice through EXM and supports the use of the form content via tokens.

http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/category/sitecore-forms-extensions/
https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions

Answer (score 0):

In Sitecore you need to write custom action for email send and add your website assemblies.dll , and the method name.

After that you need to add this new custom email send action in your email send option in Sitecore WFFM form modules. 
In this way you can send the email.

See the screenshot below:
[image]